# Is this the best way to render the sprite position each second using React-Three-Fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-hooks, react-three-fiber

I've a React project that receives a position, color & camera data from an API. These three data are been stored in main App.js states and I pass these states as a prop to R3F Canvas component.

So far, I can see it is working well. The sprites position keep moving, so does the camera. My concern is, **is this the right way to render the sprite animations?** **Will Canvas keep re-render by passing the App.js states to it?**

Here's my codes for App.js, ThreeCanvas.js & ThreeCamera.js (All are in separate files)

App.js

```
import ThreeCanvas from "./components/ThreeCanvas"

function App() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([])
  const [color, setColor] = useState([])
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState([])

  return (
    <div>
      // These p tags will keep render with the new values
      <p>Color 1: {color[0]}</p>
      <p>Color 2: {color[1]}</p>
      <p>Color 3: {color[2]}</p>
      
      // This is where ThreeCanvas component will be displayed
      <ThreeCanvas position={position} color={color} camera={camera} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

ThreeCanvas.js

```
import spriteIdleTextureImg from "../img/sprite.png"
import ThreeCamera from "./ThreeCamera"

const spriteIdleTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(spriteIdleTextureImg)

function ThreeCanvas({ position, color, camera }) {

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas colorManagement>

        // The position & color value will keep changing
        <sprite position={[position[0][0], 0, position[0][1]]}>
          <spriteMaterial map={spriteIdleTexture} color={color[0]} />
        </sprite>
        <sprite position={[position[1][0], 0, position[1][1]]}>
          <spriteMaterial map={spriteIdleTexture} color={color[1]} />
        </sprite>
        <sprite position={[position[2][0], 0, position[2][1]]}>
          <spriteMaterial map={spriteIdleTexture} color={color[2]} />
        </sprite>

        <ThreeCamera camera={camera} />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

ThreeCamera .js

```
function ThreeCamera ({ camera }) {

  useFrame(state => {
    
    // The camera state will keep changing based on the camera props data
    state.camera.fov = THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(camera.fov)
    state.camera.near = camera.near
    state.camera.far = camera.far
    state.camera.aspect = camera.aspect
    state.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    state.camera.position.set(...camera.eye)
    state.camera.up.set(...camera.up)
    state.camera.lookAt(...camera.at)
  })

  return null
}
```

Comment: How often do you fetch data from an API?

Comment: @rokob once.. but from there, they will be a method been executed which gonna keep updating the states..